# What should my job title be?

Tags: job-description, title

I'm in a weird situation. 3 years ago I made promotion at my current employer. My job title on my contract is Project Manager. Meanwhile my tasks changed depending since my qualities are on a different level.

This is what I've done in the last years:

Beside some project manager tasks I mostly done the following:

Creating DM for 2 major Telecom Providers. I've created letters in Indesign(DTP) and formatted and cleaned datasets for large mailings(10.000 - 600.000 letters). These letters included changed pricing tables etc and was conform the standards supplied by those Telecom Providers.

Did the same for e-mail, created DM templates in Dreamweaver/raw HTML and CSS and used an obscure program to send and track mass mailings.

Created Dashboards for our clients, mainly build in Excel. I have knowledge of SQL from a reporting perspective, I have advanced knowledge of Excel, Power Query and VBA.

Made analysis of datasets provided by our customers for insights in the clientbase, this for marketing purposes.

Created automated processes for exports and imports of datasets, also acted like a consultant for gathering requirements, brainstorming seasons regarding implementation and the boundaries of our technical possibilities.

Rebuild reports and dashboards that required manual input build by other employees to make them foolproof, lightweight and more professional.

Consultancy on starting new projects, from ICT impact to the commercial side of the project. Since I've done Sales myself I can communicate with marketing and sales staff on a high level.

My knowledge on different programming language is versatile, I don't know the ins and outs of every language but have no problem getting things done with SQL, MySQL, Java, Javascript, VBA and VBS. My strength lies in building whats needed in a quick and dirty manner while keeping the high over view on the whole process.

So, now we are thinking of a sufficient job title but my manager and myself can't seem to get any further than jack-of-all-trades.

Anyone here with a brilliant idea?

Comment: Why do you care about what the jobtitle should be here?

Comment: What is wrong with Project Manager? Are you managing the project or doing it all yourself?

Comment: Is there anyone in the company whose role has involved even a few tasks similar to those you have worked on? What title to they use?

Comment: @killisi All myself, atm I don't work in a project team anymore.

Comment: Principal IT?...

Comment: @Kozaky No, I'm the only one with these tasks. We have developers and reporters, but my tasks don't fit in those boundaries.

Comment: @Erik since the fushion we should have an appropriate jobtitle describing our tasks and specialties.

Comment: @we have a principal IT engineer, but that is more on the network part of our tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "Beside some project manager tasks" it seems that Project Manager would still be appropriate.

But if you really feel compelled to have your title changed, you might consider something more generic like "IT Consultant" or "IT Specialist" - whichever you prefer.

Alternatively, you or your manager should talk to HR. They typically have access to lots of research on job titles and have spent some time on titles and job paths for your company.

I'm not sure it's going to make all that much difference career-wise. The title is far less important than the details of the job and the tasks you have accomplished.

Comment: I will do so. IT Specialist would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically the title doesn't matter, the work you did in the role where you assigned a title matters.

Another side of the coin to consider is if you gave yourself a new title, lets say *Senior Project Administrator*, and a new company called your previous employer for a reference and asked:

> Hi, I'm calling from [Company]. Can you provide a reference for [Raymond P] in the job role [Senior Project Administrator]?

And your bosses reply is

> Well we employed him as a project manager...

It looks like you're embellishing your resume.